# Why can't my program use my assigned string operator to calculate the two integers?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Why can't my program use my assigned string operator to calculate the two integers? For some reason its as if the program is not accepting the input from the user.

```
import java.io.*;

public class IntCalc {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader kb = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        System.out.println ("This program performs an integer calculation of your choice.");

        System.out.println ("Enter an integer: ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt (kb.readLine());

        System.out.println ("Enter a second integer: ");
        int y = Integer.parseInt (kb.readLine());

        System.out.print ("Would you like to find the sum, difference, product, quotient, or remainder of your product?: ");
        String operator = kb.readLine();

        int finalNum;

        if (operator == "sum") {
            int finalNum = (x + y);
        } else if (operator == "difference") {
            int finalNum = (x - y);
        } else if (operator == "product") {
            int finalNum = (x * y);
        } else if (operator == "remainder") {
            int finalNum = (x % y);
        }

        System.out.print ("The " + operator + " of your two integers is " + finalNum ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `.equals()` not `==` to compare the strings. Also see [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: `finalNum "."` How does that even compile?

Comment: Check your variable scopes. As finalNum in any of your if/else if statements differ from the one defined before the if conditional, and differs from the one printed after wards.

Comment: You could also use `java.util.Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader + parseInt`. That would make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `int` declarations in your `if` statement here. Also when comparing strings use `String.equals()`. Make sure too to initialise `finalNum` or the compiler will complain.

```
int finalNum = 0;

if (operator.equals("sum"))
{
   finalNum = (x + y);
}
else if (operator.equals("difference"))
{
   finalNum = (x - y);
}   
else if (operator.equals("product"))
{
   finalNum = (x * y);
}
else if (operator.equals("remainder"))
{
   finalNum = (x % y);
}

System.out.print ("The " + operator + " of your two integers is " + finalNum + ".");
```

Comment: Hey I got a little farther in the program but am still left with one error. error: variable finalNum might not have been initialized. What could that possibly mean?

Comment: You need to to assign the local value `finalNum` similar to the way I have done it above.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using **operator == "sum"** use **operator.equals("sum")**.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- When you write `int finalNum` within your *if-statements* what you're actually doing is creating a new variable and assigning it a value. However the scope of this variable exists within that particular *if-block* only. As such, you don't see your outer *finalNum* variable getting updated.
- Consider using [`equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) to compare whether the user's input is a *sum, difference, product or a remainder*. This is because in your case, you wouldn't be bothered if the user enters *sum or SUM or Sum*, they would ideally mean the same.